# Tickets to the Koshien Bowl

Tags: tickets, japan, sports-events, osaka

I'm looking to attend the [Koshien Bowl](http://koshienbowl.kir.jp/2015/contents/english.html) final on December 13th. Does anyone know how I'd go about getting tickets? I'll be in Japan for a few days before the game (but not in Kobe/Osaka.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get tickets at nearly any convenience store in the nation; although I don't think that any of the kiosks do ticket sales in English. If you have someone who can read Japanese, going to 7/11, Family Mart, etc is the easiest way.

[This page](http://koshienbowl.kir.jp/2015/contents/ticket.html) lists the various ticket outlets.

Comment: This worked out great! There's an English-speaking [TicketPia counter at Narita](http://www.narita-airport.jp/en/guide/service/list/svc_69.html) that hooked me right up. It was useful though to have the Japanese language print out of the Koshien Bowl site to aid in looking up the event.

Comment: Glad you enjoyed it.  I did not know about the airport counters. Great find!